# css variables are not properly processed in scss files

Tags: css, sass

I have a problem with css variables used in scss files.

When it's used as a pure value works fine, for example:
iside file
**theme.css**

```
:root {
    --app-bg-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

and inside *header.scss* file:

```
...
    background: linear-gradient(0.25turn, var(--app-bg-color), rgba(var(--app-bg-color), 0.7));
...
```

> **var(--app-bg-color)** works fine,
> but

> **rgba(var(--app-bg-color), 0.7)** is not working properly

and I have got an error:

> **Error: /styles/header.scss:30:8: Unable to parse color from string "var(--app-bg-color)"**

This is a part of **babel.config.js**:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        },
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                modules: {
                    localIdentName: '[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
                },
                importLoaders: 1,
            },
        },
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                syntax: 'postcss-scss',
                plugins: getSassPlugins({ isProd: false }),
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

I can't find, why it's not working;
Do You have any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that you are passing HEX color code to the rgba css function?

Comment: Not exactly, when define at top of a file a variable  like $gradientColor: #f0f0f0, and later it's used as an argument of rgba($gradientColor, 0,7) everythings work fine

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because rgba does not accept HEX values, you have to indicate an RGBA format, that you can do with SASS in the following way: `rgba(#f0f0f0, 0.7);`